# How to separate columns with a line in beamer(poster)?

Tags: beamer, rules, columns, beamerposter

`\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}` with the multicol package does not work. The beamer guide does not discuss this case for their columns environment...

To be clear this is what I want

###### | ###### | ######
 ###### | ###### | ######
 ###### | ###### | ######
 ###### | ###### | ######
 ###### | ###### | ######
 ###### | ###### | ######

Comment: Looks kike a job for a `tabular`?

Comment: Ok, from my example I agree it looks that way, but my example is butchered by the fact I do not know yet how to insert line breaks here. Sorry. I only wanted to draw 3 columns...

Comment: Also, I need it in the columns environment so I can use beamerposter's blocks inside the columns.

Comment: @MTAL: If you want to force a line break, you need to end the line with two spaces before pressing enter. And for some reason, if a line starts with a `#` you need to put a space before it, otherwise it gets gobbled.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please provide a minimal working example? The reason is that it works for me:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}

\newcommand{\sometext}{{\footnotesize Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore }}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{3 columns}
        \begin{multicols}{3}
         \sometext\sometext\sometext\sometext\sometext\sometext\sometext
        \end{multicols}
    \end{frame}     
\end{document}
```

creates this:

[image]

**EDIT:** Oh, I totally overlooked the `beamerposter`. Thats why a MWE would have been nice, no forgetting upon Ctrl + C and inserting in my editor ;)

But anyway, it still works for me:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}

\newcommand{\sometext}
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
}

\newcommand{\moretext}[1]
{   \foreach \x in {1,2,...,#1}
    {   \sometext
    }
}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{3 columns}
        \begin{multicols}{3}
            \moretext{7}
        \end{multicols}
    \end{frame}     
\end{document}
```

produces this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it seems to work in beamer. But when I try to use it in my beamerposter template, things go crazy.

Comment: I'll try some more variations, and if I get something working I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of doing it in artificial way. Just create a third column and adjust the columns' width accordingly. The mid column contains a vertical ruler.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}[c]
\begin{column}{.475\textwidth}
\begin{block}{Column 1}
Column 1
\end{block}
\end{column}

% artificial column for vertical ruler
\begin{column}{.05\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\rule{1pt}{\textheight}
\end{center}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{.475\textwidth}
\begin{block}{Column 2}
Column 2
\end{block}
\end{column}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document} %end
```