# How to draw a line between columns in beamerposter, reaching from header to bottom?

Tags: rules, multicol, beamerposter

I am trying to make a poster using the beamerposter package and have a line below a header block (containing title, authors etc.). Now I want to draw a vertical line in the middle of the poster (separating the columns), that starts at the header line and ends at the lower end of the poster.

I already found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26216/how-to-separate-columns-with-a-line-in-beamerposter) very similar question, but the line there is only as short as possible. Here is a MWE with the short vertical line:

```
\documentclass[final,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}                   

\setlength{\columnseprule}{2mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{headline}
    \centering\huge{Headline and stuff}
    \rule{\paperwidth}{2mm}
  \end{beamercolorbox}

  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \huge some text\\
    some more text
  \end{multicols}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can I draw a longer vertical line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this really answers your question; printing half of the horizontal rule, a very long vertical one (but "smashed", so its length is not "seen" by TeX) and the other half rule seems to work.

I use some low level commands, so to avoid some glitches with `\rule`.

```
\documentclass[final,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}                   
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\setlength{\columnseprule}{2mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{headline}
    \centering\huge Headline and stuff\\
    \rule{.5\paperwidth}{2mm}\kern-1mm
    \smash{\vrule height 0pt depth \paperheight width 2mm}\kern-1mm
    \rule{.5\paperwidth}{2mm}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}

  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \huge \lipsum[1-3]
  \end{multicols}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do not really understand what the TeX commands do, but your solution works perfectly. Thank you!